# How dangerous is it to use ProcessInfo.processInfo.environment in production app ?

Tags: ios, swift, unit-testing, core-data, production-environment

I wrote a mock `Coredata` manager in order to test some classes in unit tests.

I have about 10 classes that get's `NSManagedObjectContext` from a class called `DatabaseManager`. I have decided if unit tests are running, don't deal with actual `Coredata NSManagedObjectContext` but redirect to `Mock Coredata` Class to get the `NSManagedObjectContext`.

```
func getContext() -> NSManagedObjectContext {
    if ProcessInfo.processInfo.environment["XCTestConfigurationFilePath"] == nil 
    {
        return persistentContainer.viewContext
    }
    else
    {
        return MockDatabaseController.instance.managedObjectContext()
    }
}
```

This works pretty well in Unit tests and debugging and when distributed thru adhoc too.

But my concern is if it ever fails to get the correct value from `ProcessInfo.processInfo.environment["XCTestConfigurationFilePath"]` app will probably be useless.

How viable is it to use `ProcessInfo.processInfo.environment["XCTestConfigurationFilePath"]` in production code ?

Comment: I would avoid it, if anything, because having dependancies on things external to your app's repository (including env vars) is a headache.

Comment: How would you solve the coredata problem then? I dont want my unit tests to interact with the actual coredata context.

Comment: It's not the job of this class to know anything about your mocks. The code that depend on the core data serivce (mock or real) should take that dependency as a parameter to their initializer. The prod code will provide the real implementation, whereas the test code will provide the mock.

Comment: And of course, define a protocol that's shared by the two (or more, who knows) data providers, and have everything coupled to the protocol, rather than tightly coupled to any one of its concrete implementations

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use Swift conditional compilation along with -D flags passed in the build arguments to make sure that the code was only active in test environments and never had the opportunity to make it into production.